# Restrict content based on buy woocommerce product

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, content-restriction

How i can restrict portion of post/page content when user bought specific product?

for example:

```
    some content
...
        [wcm_restrict product_id="5"]
        this content only show for users that bought product 5
        [/wcm_restrict]
...
    some other content
```

I tried many plug-ins unfortunately doesn't have this feature.
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to make this shortcode already? This is a good approach, but provide us with the shortcode function to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @MilanPetrovic No, It's just an example. can you suggest a plugin for me? or only possible with code?

Comment: I can't give you advice for the plugin, I don't know specifically if some plugin has such shortcode. It would not be too difficult to make the shortcode for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I answering my question.

As @Milan Petrovic mentioned in comments, it's easy to do. just creating shortcode and check if user bought specific product.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * [wcr_shortcode description]
 * @param  array  pid    product id from short code
 * @return content          shortcode content if user bought product
 */
function wcr_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
{
    // normalize attribute keys, lowercase
    $atts = array_change_key_case((array) $atts, CASE_LOWER);

    // start output
    $o = '';

    // start box
    $o .= '<div class="wcr-box">';

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( current_user_can('administrator') || wc_customer_bought_product($current_user->email, $current_user->ID, $atts['pid'])) {
        // enclosing tags
        if (!is_null($content)) {
            // secure output by executing the_content filter hook on $content
            $o .= apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        }

    } else {
        // User doesn't bought this product and not an administator
    }
    // end box
    $o .= '</div>';

    // return output
    return $o;
}

add_shortcode('wcr', 'wcr_shortcode');
```

Shortcode usage example:

```
[wcr pid="72"]
 This content only show for users that bought product with the id #72
[/wcr]
```

### References

1. [Shortcodes with Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce provides a [function](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_customer_bought_product.html) to do this.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id ) ) {
    _e( 'This content is only visible for users who bought this product.' );
}
```

Comment: thank you @jesse for your answer. I've solved my question.